# C# datatable Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, datagridview

I have two objects `people` and `house`, and I want to show the table people in a datagridview, but in the field `House`, the value shown is `Program.Model.House`; I want to show the street name instead, how I can do it? (I'm using Entity Framework and the data source of data grid view I use `context.tolist()`)

```
public class People 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public House House { get; set; }
}

public class House
{
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override ToString() in House class. Like that :

```
public override string ToString(){ return $"Street: {Street}"; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You wanted to show data like  `Name` and `Street Name`

For Name You can use `Model.Name`

For Street Name you can use `Model.House.Street`

For Example

```
 @foreach(var item in Model)
 {
       <td> @Model.Name</td>
       <td> @Model.House.Street</td>
 }
```

May this help you

Answer (score 0):

Simply create a new object for grid view with a street name.

````
List<object> peopleData=new List<object>(); 
peopleData.Add(new{ ppl.Name,ppl.House.Street });

grdPeople.DataSource = peopleData;```
````